# Windows 10 1809 cannot search for emoji

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language, windows-10-v1809

When I press `Win` + `.` and start typing I get:

[image: emoji picker]

The Windows display language is set to Dutch and it is also set as preferred language. 
When I press options, the keyboard layout is set to US International. I cannot seem to find out what setting is wrong or missing. I have the Dutch (and English) lang pack installed from the Microsoft Store.

ps. the translation of the screenshot is something like this:
the base function for typing has to be installed in order to use search queries.
Open the settings of region and language to download this component in the settings of your language.

Comment: In which application is this happening?

Comment: It's OS wide. Not a specific application.

Comment: With me `Win` + `.` only minimizes the current window. Is this some installed application?

Comment: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/02/05/windows-10-tip-get-started-emoji-keyboard-shortcut/ https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enable-windows-10-emoji-picker-outside-united-states

Comment: Another useful link [here](https://thommck.wordpress.com/2021/12/23/fix-emoji-search-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot fixed it.  Did not wanted to delete or close this, because it might just help someone.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me also. After reading about how emojis are supported by OS, I found what was the issue in my case: searching would not work when I switched the keyboard from `ENG (English)` to ROU `(Romanian)`. After pressing `LEFT ALT+SHIFT` (or `WIN KEY + SPACE`) to switch back to ENG, searching works again.

In fact, searching works on ROU keyboard as well, but I have to write the name of the emoji in Romanian: eg: `thumbs up` is translated as `semn de aprobare`
[image]