# Windows 10 1809 cannot search for emoji - restart did not fix

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language, windows-10-v1809

When I press <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> and start typing I get (shown is MS Teams, but same happens in other applications also):

[image: error message when searching emoji]

The Windows display language is set to English

[image: windows language settings]

I have tried restarting the laptop per this other question, but no luck: [Windows 10 1809 cannot search for emoji](https://superuser.com/questions/1375604/windows-10-1809-cannot-search-for-emoji)

Comment: Suspect the problem is your language pack doesn’t contain emoji icons.  Switch to a different language pack like **English (United States)**

Comment: @Ramhound I do see the emojis when not searching, and can scroll through and use them also. It's just search that is broken. Would have expected all emoji use to fail if pack does not contain emojis??

Comment: Search is handled by Cortana which is only supported with certain languages (and regions).  Which is the reason I suggested switching languages for the display language as a simple test.

Comment: @Ramhound It appears that language packs are different on different Win 10 versions. on my 1909 machine, this works fine for several packs (e.g. English (Ireland), English (United Kingdom) all of which have additional options (e.g. regional, handwriting, speech, additional speech). On 1809, these options are simply not available for the same language packs.

Comment: Emoji support requires OS support.  You can’t expect an emoji emoji that exists in 1909 to exist in 1809 depending on the emoji

Comment: I'm not expecting emojis to exit, I'm expecting to be able to search the ones that do exist (the image in the question with no emoji is only when I start typing to search, I can use the mouse to select them no problem)

Comment: Windows Search is substantially different in 1809 compared to 1909

Comment: I'm on 1909 and emoji search doesn't work in any field. edit: it *used* to work, don't know what changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened to me also. After reading about how emojis are supported by OS, I found what was the issue in my case: searching would not work when I switched the keyboard from `ENG (English)` to `ROU (Romanian)`. After pressing `LEFT ALT+SHIFT` (or `WIN KEY + SPACE`) to switch back to `ENG`, searching works again.

In fact, searching works on ROU keyboard as well, but I have to write the name of the emoji in Romanian: eg: `thumbs up` is translated as `semn de aprobare`

[image]

Comment: Wow, you nailed it. I have two keyboard layouts and didn't notice that the different applications use different ones. Was wondering why only in notepad I see "Emoji - Keep typing to find an emoji", while in all other apps it is just "Emoji". 

Comment: Yes, started working now for me if I switch language pack to "English (United States)". The keyboard setting for the language pack does not seem to affect it. Even selecting "English (United Kingdom)" language pack does not work, which is kind of odd as the languages are pretty similar.

Comment: @Toby thanks! For me `English (Germany)` didn't work. After switching to `English (US)` the search works again as expected.

Comment: @winklerr I imagine most language packs have most emoticons, I suggest you manually look for the emoticon and see its name in your case

Comment: @botismarius nah, that wasn't the problem for me. In my case I wasn't even able to type a character while `English (Germany)` was selected. The emoticon view just seemed to be frozen (despite clicking the emoticons worked but not the keyboard input).

Comment: But what if you only use one keyboard layout? Only the US International layout on an English version of Windows exhibits the same problem...